# Unexpected console output while importing `Requests` python module

Tags: python, request

when I import `requests` I get an unexpected output of a list of numbers.

```
>>> import requests
[4, 4, 324, 342, 342, 453, 4343, 43342]
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Did you edit the `__init__`in the requests' folder? Do you have a script called requests.py in the same folder as your current script?

Comment: Check the value of `requests.__file__`.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Nopes I didn't edit that file, neither do I have requests.py file in the current directory :| 
This is the content of __init__.py in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests` http://pastebin.com/buPb8vwe

Comment: Ah, I deleted `__init__.pyc` , that solved the problem ! I wonder how this print list statement got in `.pyc` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably have a `requests.py` (or a requests folder with `__init__.py` file , which is causing that to be treated as a package) most probably in the current directory (or one of the directories in `sys.path`) that is masking the `requests` module from library .

It should be this `requests.py` that is printing this list of numbers.

Like indicated in the comments you can check the file which is getting imported by doing -

```
import requests
print(requests.__file__)
```

You should rename your package/script file such that it does not shadow any libraries.

Comment: Thanks! 
It was using compiled python file `__init__.pyc` which was printing the list. I deleted this file and it fixed the problem. I wonder how the print list command got in the `.pyc` file !

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons and their fixes :

1) You probably have `requests.py` file in same folder where your python.
   Check this and rename your `requests.py` file.

2) You probably have changed `__init__` function in requests.py.

Remember `__init__` function is automatically called and executed when you import that module.